# How do I replace the text to a link in php?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, string, function

I have the following function in my wordpress website, works well with page text......

```
function replace_text($text) {
    $text = str_replace('Cookbook', 'All Recipes', $text);
    $text = str_replace('look-for-that-string', 'replace-with-that-string', $text);
return $text;
}
add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text');
```

But what I'm trying to target is text that is generated by a menu plugin,....
I've tried by adding the actual element code (below) in it's entirety but it does not change the menu text. It still say "Cookbook" I can't touch the menu plugin code unfortunately.

```
 function replace_text($text) {
     $text = str_replace('<span class="145-test 120-test 115-test loaded- 
header">Cookbook</span>', '<span class="145-test 120-test 115-test loaded-header">All Recipes</span>', $text);
$text = str_replace('look-for-that-string', 'replace-with-that-string', $text);
return $text;
 }
 add_filter('the_content', 'replace_text');
```

Is there something I need so that it switches the text?

does it have to do with the_content?

Comment: Maybe because of cache, clear cache in browser and cache folder of WordPress.

Comment: Even if I know it works on the page?

Comment: @TheoE what????

Comment: Are you sure that the menu plugin is actually going through the filter `the_content` ? `the_content` filter is usually only used when outputting the content of a page not a menu.  Is this a navigation menu you created from backend under **Appearance > Menus**? If its a navigation menu you should use `wp_nav_menu_items` filter as in this link: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_nav_menu_items/

Comment: Also another suggestion would be to change the title of your question to a more specific one, since it does not actually describe your problem.

Comment: its not a menu. i want to target the link in a widget.